# Facebook canvas app link sharing on wall gives oauth error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I share my facebook Canvas App's link on my wall, I see the app image fine but then in the app description area I get Fatal Error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user...
Also when I debug the link the debugger says it's valid but when I try the Scraped URL I get the same error.
I understand that because I query the user in the index page of my app I get this error but how can I make facebook **scraper** to not give me this error.

The canvas app link is :
https://apps.facebook.com/warriorofnemesis

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason and I will answer my own question, in case somebody else faces the same problem. The reason I see this Oauth error message was , because the display_errors setting was set to true in my script. I had done it to find a error on my page and forgot that I had this setting True. After I turned it off , now it works ok.